# How can I disable the bold and italic keyboard shortcuts in lexicaljs?

Tags: reactjs, lexicaljs

I'm using Lexical, and I'm trying to disable the bold and italic shortcuts .. and possibly all keyboard shortcuts. how can I do that?

I don't want to disable they keyevents listeners from javascript. is there a lexical way of doing it?